# How to create a dialog style that looks as snackbar style

Tags: android, dialog, styles

I am trying to write a custom dialog style that will give me the styling of a snackbar where the dialog is anchored at the bottom of the screen where there is no gap between the box and the navigation control and takes up full width of the screen.
[sample_look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPDUg.png)
How do i style this?

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want dialog to appear at bottom , then you can set the gravity appropriately .

`Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);`

You can also use bottomsheet dialog .